CDCR Replication is not working in solr 8.11.2
I have setup CDCR IN Azure VM with 3 nodes and 3 zookeeper
`My Solr version is 8.11.2 Zookeeper =v3.6.2
I have setup source and target cluster with below configuration in source, We are not able to see the replicated data in target cluster and getting warning like Log reader for target collection4 is not initialised ,​ it will be ignored. And no error as such

  
    11.0.0.68:2182,11.0.0.69:2182,11.0.0.70:2182/chroot/solr  ==I tried giving 11.0.0.68:2182,11.0.0.69:2182,11.0.0.70:2182 like this as well
    collection4
    collection4
  
  
    8
    1000
    128
  
  
    1000
  

  
   
      ${solr.ulog.dir:}
      ${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}
    
Please help how to resolve this error.
We tried replicating from source to target but it is not happening and not getting as error also .
Warning which we are seeing is Log reader for target collection4 is not initialised,&#8203
